# name 'stop_words' is not defined

Tags: python

What Am I doing wrong? I already defined it but it keeps on saying its not defined.

```
# Pre-process the comments

def preprocess_text(text):
    # Lowercase the text
    text = text.lower()
    # Remove punctuations
    text = re.sub(r'\[^\\w\\s\]', '', text)
    # Tokenize the text
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    stop_words.update(["a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "by", 
        "for", "from", "has", "he", "in", "is", "it", "its", "of", "on", 
        "that", "the", "to", "was", "were", "will", "with"])
    words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words]
    return words

comments_processed = [preprocess_text(comment) for comment in comments]

# Perform sentiment analysis on the comments

sentiments = []
for comment in comments:
    sentiment = TextBlob(comment).sentiment.polarity
    sentiments.append(sentiment)

# Identify the top 3 best and worst things about the product

positive_features = {}
negative_features = {}
for i in range(len(comments)):
    comment = comments[i]
    sentiment = sentiments[i]
    words = preprocess_text(comment)
    for word in words:
    if sentiment > 0:
        if word in positive_features:
            positive_features[word] += 1
        else:
            positive_features[word] = 1
    elif sentiment < 0:
        if word in negative_features:
            negative_features[word] += 1
    else:
        negative_features[word] = 1

top_positive_features = sorted(positive_features, key=positive_features.get, reverse=True)[:3]
top_negative_features = sorted(negative_features, key=negative_features.get, reverse=True)[:3]

# Visualize the results using word clouds

positive_cloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, background_color='white', stopwords=stop_words, min_font_size=10).generate_from_frequencies(positive_features)
negative_cloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, background_color='white', stopwords=stop_words, min_font_size=10).generate_from_frequencies(negative_features)
```

What is wrong here?

```
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1612\1814734049.py in <module>
         63 
         64 # Visualize the results using word clouds
    ---> 65 positive_cloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, 
    background_color='white', stopwords=stop_words, 
    min_font_size=10).generate_from_frequencies(positive_features)
         66 
         67 negative_cloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800, 
    background_color='white', stopwords=stop_words, 
    min_font_size=10).generate_from_frequencies(negative_features)

NameError: name 'stop_words' is not defined
```

Comment: Please fix indentation and `\\` escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Your stop_words is defined only in the function `preprocess_text()`, so it's scope is limited to only that function.